# Is is possible to use a custom notification library in react-admin instead of the built-in notifications?

Tags: react-admin

I would like to use this toast library instead of the built in notifications in react-admin https://github.com/jossmac/react-toast-notifications

Currently I raise errors from the DataProviders which are caught by react-admin which internally handles showing the notification. I don't see any way to hook in a custom notifications library or to replace the existing showNotification functionality.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I raised this on the react-admin github issues page and got the response that I should ask on StackOverflow and that it should be possible to replace the whole Notification component with a hand rolled one in user land. But it's not very clear to me how this could be done. (https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/5035)

Comment: Maybe this is what you were looking for: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Theming.html#notifications

Comment: Yes - great thanks